# Having Qt read-only model and view in different threads

Tags: qt, qthread, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel

As I learn from Qt docs, in Qt Model/View framework, models and their attached views should live in the same (GUI) thread. This might lead to some undesirable effects like the following. I have subclassed `QAbstractTableModel` and implemented the required virtual functions. Internally, the model makes queries into sqlite database which have lots of records, and provides the data accordingly to attached views via reimplemented `data()` function.

Now, in GUI I have a `QTableView`, which I attached to that model. Also I have a `QLineEdit` input field. Printing text in this field emits a `textChanged()` signal, which is connected to a (custom) `query()` slot of the model. In this way, typing a new character in the input field should update the table with the records matching the typed phrase.

Well, as my database is large, I do not expect the table updating to follow immediately after typing another letter - updating waits for the query to complete which might take a second or two.

But what bothers me is that since I am obliged to have model and table in the same GUI thread, the input field also friezes after each letter untill the table is updated. I would like to make it such that I might type the phrase without freezing effect, and let wait the table to update. Notifying the model only when the entire phrase is typed with pressing Enter is not an option for me - I need the `textChanged()` signal to work.

So then I thought - would it be of a big offend to Qt if I ignore the docs and put the model into a non-GUI thread? To my surprise, it worked! Now typing does not freeze, and the program does not crash (at least for now).

So my question is - is it nonetheless unsafe to use model in a non-GUI thread, and my program might suddenly crash any other day? I also should mention that I want to use the model in a read-only way. If I need to change data underlying the model, I will not do it using the view/delegates, I will just send appropriate signals to the model's thread, and all changes will be performed within that thread.

Comment: If the database query is slow, why don't you move only that part to a new thread, why do you have to move the whole model? [`QFileSystemModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html) does something like this.

Comment: Probably because I don't quite understand how it would be different. Say, I have a `QTableView` and `QAbstractItemTable` in one thread, and then I also create a third object called, say, `dataEngine` in a different thread. This objects actually handles sqlite queries. To view data in my table, I still need to implement the `data()` method of the model, and so in this case I'll have to seek into another thread from the `data()`? I would appreciate a minimal algorithm involving `beginResetModel` and `endResetModel` interacting with the `dataEngine` thread.

Comment: Before considering threading approach I would think on the reasons why it's slow. Please take into account that even your database is large, views will always show only relatively small amount of data at a time, and this amount is limited by your screen size. Maybe you could rather make your queries faster?

Comment: It's just the structure of the database is rather complex. First, I have really many records, second, there are multiple joins in the query. So select statements might take up to a second or two. But this is not the only reason I want sqlite to be handled in a different thread - sometimes I need to insert larger numbers of records, and the GUI also freezes at these moments (even though I use sqlite transactions, inserting might take up a few seconds, since I have special data validating procedures).

Comment: Another (or additional) approach to improve performance might be to use a delay timer before firing the query/update based on user input. E.g. a `QTimer` with a short timeout value which (re)starts on every `textChanged()`. Only update the table when it times out. In any case it adds the advantage of eliminating some queries which are already outdated (because user has entered more characters). Otherwise, I think _thuga_'s suggestion is good. Also perhaps ["lazy loading"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#performance-optimization-for-large-amounts-of-data) may be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this example of removing the last row:

Synchronous (same thread)

1. `emit beginRemoveRows(int r = last row)`

   - view reacts and removes references to r
2. remove r from model
3. `endRemoveRows()`

   - view knows it may repaint

Asynchronous (different threads)

1. `emit beginRemoveRows(r)`
2. remove r from model
3. `endRemoveRows()`

Both signals are in the event queue of the GUI thread.

If the GUI event queue contains a repaint event *before* the `beginRemoveRows()`, the view will call `model->data(r)` and your program will likely crash*.

(*) Or at least run into the safeties of your `data()` implementation, but there are other things under the hood like `QPersistentModelIndex` which you don't control...